# When to use the reversed builtin instead of list slicing

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, reverse

In python, there are a number of ways to reverse a sequence:

```
l = [1,2,3]
reversed(l) #returns a reverse iterator
l[::-1] #returns a reverse sequence
```

Although there is a builtin specifically for reversing a sequence, it is more concise to use list slicing. Additionally, list slicing returns a full `Sequence`, which supports `__getitem__` and `__len__`, while `reversed` is only an iterator. Finally, `reversed` requires a `Sequence`, which means that list slicing will almost always work.

What are the advantages of using the `reversed` builtin over list slicing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list[::-1]` returns a new reversed copy of the list. It will consume more memory according to the size of the list: sizeof the list object + sizeof(pointer) * len(list)

If you don't need the whole list items at once, using [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) is more preferable in terms of memory. (For example, iterating the list reversed order, processing items one by one does not require all items at once.)

Comment: It won't consume as much as memory as the original list because the pointers in the new list still point to the same objects in memory(shallow copy). The extra memory will be **size of list object + 4 * len(lst)**.(4 for each pointer, an empty list's size is around 36 Bytes on my system)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't quite correct to say "`reversed` requires a sequence". in Python 2.6+ `reversed` works on any object that defines a `__reversed__` method. Thus it can work on objects that do not support integer indexing, while slicing can't.

So, use slicing when reversing only a segment of a sequence, need more than one element at a time, or perhaps need to control the step size. Use `reversed` if you only need to iterate through every element (as per the memory considerations of @falsetru's answer), or if you have an object with custom-defined reversing behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Oh darn, a commenter pointed out that rev_func wasn't returning a list, it was returning the list iterator.  oops

When I corrected it, the results are essentially the same.

> Using [::-1]: 1.6161760782445813 
>   Using reversed(): 1.7324838771408098

```
import timeit
import random

def rev_slice(big_list):
    return big_list[::-1]


def rev_func(big_list):

    #return reversed(big_list)
    return list(reversed(big_list))


big_list = [random.random() for i in range(10000000)]

slice_t = timeit.Timer("foo = rev_slice(big_list)", "from __main__ import big_list, rev_slice")
slice_time = slice_t.timeit(10)
print ("Using [::-1]: {0}".format(slice_time))

func_t = timeit.Timer("foo = rev_func(big_list)", "from __main__ import big_list, rev_func")
func_time = func_t.timeit(10)
print ("Using reversed(): {0}".format(func_time))
```

Comment: It's because reversed returns an iterator, no list creation or loop is happening in that process. So that doesn't depends on list size at all, hence constant time.

Comment: Oh darn, yeah, you're right.  And once-fixed, the results are essentially the same, perhaps even tiny slower for reversed().